# Are there HTTP Client/Server components for Delphi that support iOS?

Tags: ios, delphi, http, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe4

I am developing a program in Delphi/Object Pascal that acts as an HTTP request router on various platforms.  It's a sort of proxy that is designed to pass through certain HTTP requests and field others locally.  I have it running on Windows, and would now like to port it to iOS.

The program currently uses the Indy Internet component suite to implement an HTTP Client and HTTP Server.  I recently discovered that although these components will compile successfully to iOS using Delphi XE4, they are not supported and will not run.

I am looking for a workable option.  I am aware of other component suites such as IP*Works and  RealThinClient, but have no experience with them.

Has anyone developed an HTTP Client/HTTP Server application in this environment? I realize that Delphi support for iOS is quite new, as XE4 has only just been released.  But XE2 had an iOS solution based on FreePascal (which I initially used to create my program in Lazarus to port to Linux & MacOS).  Also XE4 has been in beta test up until this week.  So it's possible someone may have tried this by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XE4 feature matrix](http://www.embarcadero.co.uk/products/delphi/delphi-feature-matrix) states:

> New in XE4! Indy for iOS

So I believe you can use the version of Indy that ships with the product. It's possible that you are building from out of date source.

Comment: So it does! Thank you! I missed this. But now I have to figure out why my app doesn't work. I will investigate.

Comment: @pmanion According to what Remy published to the INDY group it's a good idea to update your INDY to what's in the project's trunk.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The answer is in my next posted question: #16328319

Answer (score 1):

Internet Direct (Indy), the communications library that comes with Delphi, supports iOS.

Comment: Thank you. And David Heffernan's post confirms that this feature is supported in the features matrix.